# How do I get SOAP xml file data using LINQ and display it in a form's text box? C#

Tags: c#, linq, soap, linq-to-xml

How do I do it?
This is the SOAP XML file

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" >
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:lle="http://www.aab.org/logevents" >
        <lle:Events>
            <lle:eventid>ID1</lle:eventid>
                <lle:tweet>
                    <lle:text>This is some tweet in my day</lle:text>
                    <lle:location>
                        <lle:lat>66</lle:lat>
                        <lle:long>77</lle:long>
                    </lle:location>
                    <lle:datetimestamp>datetimestamp</lle:datetimestamp>
                </lle:tweet>
        </lle:Events>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is my C# code, it doesn't display anything in the text box, I have tried adding the "lle:" in front of "Event" and its Descendants like:

> .Descendants("lle:Events")
> select events.Element("lle:eventid").Value;
> but apparently it doesn't work, and there's lots of errors, so I changed it back

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    
    namespace Xmltest
    {
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument();


            IEnumerable<string> id = from events in XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Jack\source\repos\xmltest\Xmltest\XmlFile.xml")
                                       .Descendants("Events")
                                       select events.Element("eventid").Value;
            

            this.txtBox1.Text = id.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

but it worked perfectly fine with normal xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer ID="101">
    <Name>Robert</Name>
    <Mobile>9820098200</Mobile>
    <Location>Bangladesh</Location>
    <Address>XYZ</Address>
  </Customer>
  <Customer ID="102">
    <Name>Kate</Name>
    <Mobile>983452342</Mobile>
    <Location>Japan</Location>
    <Address>ABC</Address>
  </Customer>
  <Customer ID="103">
    <Name>Catherine</Name>
    <Mobile>123456785</Mobile>
    <Location> London</Location>
    <Address>CDE</Address>
  </Customer>
  <Customer ID="10004">
    <Name>Richard</Name>
    <Mobile>899990012</Mobile>
    <Location>France</Location>
    <Address>MNO</Address>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Comment: There are no `Event` descendants (there are `Events`). Do you actually have that xml file on disk? Because it looks like the return from a web service. If it is actually a web service, you would be better to create a connection the service and generate the serialization code in Visual Studio. See, for example: https://medium.com/grensesnittet/integrating-with-soap-web-services-in-net-core-adebfad173fb

Comment: Use  ToString() : this.txtBox1.Text = id.ToString();

Comment: @Jonathan Opps, but it still doesn't work after changing the word `Events` and yes I do have the xml file on disk.

Comment: @jdweng `id.ToString()` doesn't work at all, went to Google and got the answer from various resources, by using `id.First()`, `id.FirstOrDefault()`, `id.Single()` and `id.SingleOrDefault()` all of these works fine without error, just that it doesn't show anything on the text box.

Comment: Id .String() should work.  If you got nothing there is something else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's because you are using strings to refer to element. You should use XName, e.g. instead of "Events" or "eventid" use:

```cs
var events = XName.Get("Events", "http://www.aab.org/logevents");
var eventId =  XName.Get("eventid", "http://www.aab.org/logevents");
```

You can use below powershell snippet for a quick test:

```
$x = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load("C:\Users\Jack\source\repos\xmltest\Xmltest\XmlFile.xml")

$evtName = [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get("Events", "http://www.aab.org/logevents")
$idName = [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get("eventid", "http://www.aab.org/logevents")

$x.Descendants($evtName).Element($idName).Value | Write-Host
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the Xml Namespace. You can do this by querying with `XName`, instead of with a string:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inXml = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"" soapenv:encodingStyle=""http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding"" >
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:lle=""http://www.aab.org/logevents"" >
        <lle:Events>
            <lle:eventid>ID1</lle:eventid>
                <lle:tweet>
                    <lle:text>This is some tweet in my day</lle:text>
                    <lle:location>
                        <lle:lat>66</lle:lat>
                        <lle:long>77</lle:long>
                    </lle:location>
                    <lle:datetimestamp>datetimestamp</lle:datetimestamp>
                </lle:tweet>
        </lle:Events>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
    
        var eventIdsXName = XName.Get("eventid", "http://www.aab.org/logevents");

        var eventIds = XDocument.Parse(inXml)
            .Descendants(eventIdsXName)
            .Select(i => i.Value);
        
        foreach(var eventId in eventIds){
            Console.WriteLine($"Value: {eventId}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Value: ID1

See:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/IEdwz1